# is there a co-Stokes theorem? (with the codifferential)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am trying to read through J. Simmons, *Minimal Varieties in Riemannian Manifolds*, and in the proof of Proposition 1.2.2 he calls "Stokes theorem" to the following result:
$$
\int_M\delta\theta=\int_{\partial M}\star\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is a 1-form on $M$, $\delta$ is the codifferential and $\star$ is the Hodge star operator.

I looked for "stokes codifferential" on the internet. In google or in MO it didn't give anything. On MSE there is [this unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427098/if-the-boundary-is-adjoint-to-the-differential-what-is-the-coboundary-adjoint).

Is this result explained in some book? I don't do differential geometry and I don't know the literature.

Comment: Note that in this case $\delta \theta$ is the function $-*d*\theta$. When one says "integrate a function over M", they mean the n-form $fd\text{vol}_n = *f$. So the left-hand-side really means $\int -d*\theta$. The given statement is Stokes' theorem applied to the 1-form $*\theta$, except that (unless I have made a sign error) there is a missing minus sign somewhere.

Comment: @nme okay, that explains it then, thx.